# Play 2.0 Comet using a persistant connection

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using play 2.0 for a realtime web application that connects to a backend socket in order to listen for data on that stream.

The following example does what I want but I don't know how to disconnect the socket if the clients webpage is closed or page has changed.

```
def comet = Action {

  val out = Enumerator.imperative[String]()
  val socketClient = new SocketClientModel("localhost", "testclient", 
    Option("username"), "password", out)
  socketClient.listen

  Ok.stream(out &> Comet(callback = "console.log"))
}
```

The problem that I am having is figuring out how to call socketClient.disconnect when the page has been closed or changed.  Currently when I close the browser session I can still see the connection is established and data is being received on the server side.

Comment: I think it's not possible with comet (but i'm not an expert ;) What about to use Websocket ?

Comment: I already have websocket's working correctly.  Unfortunately I need to be able to support IE? Therefor I need to be able to fall back to comet.

Answer (score 4):

A hacky solution could be for you to have a ping call in the other direction (client to server):

- You setup a timer that will destroy the connection if it hasn't been canceled before 10 seconds (you can always setup a longer period):

  ```
  var timer; 

  def comet = Action {
       timer = Akka.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(10 seconds) {
         socketClient.disconnect
       }
  ...
  }
  ```
- You setup an Action that receives pings and setup a timer in the javascript code to send requests to that route every 9 seconds:

  ```
  def keepAlive = Action {
      cancel.cancel
        timer = Akka.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(10 seconds) {
            socketClient.disconnect
        }
  }
  ```

When the user goes to another page, or cancel the connection to the comet Action, then it should also cancel the ping timer on the client side (if the user change page, this should be automatic, but you will have to have some health check on the comet connection if you stay in the same page, etc.). When the client stops pinging your action, the timer will eventually kill the socket.

It's really ugly as you need to use a `var` that is shared between your two actions and it's not really thread safe. It also would only be able to support one client. But the code example you have given is the same I guess. You would need to track which session has open which socket to support multiple client. You would loose stateless behaviour though.

A cleaner solution would be to use a small actor system to encapsulate this behaviour:
  - you have a SocketActor that, when it receives a Start message, opens a socket and pushes things on a PushEnumerator, it keeps doing this as long as it doesn't receive a Stop message. 
  - you also have a KeepAliveActor that will after a given amount of time send a Stop message to the SocketActor, unless it has received a KeepAlive message before (so, what's going on here).

When you receive a comet connection, you spawn two new actors (you should have a manager actor to hide the two actors and relay the messages, etc.) and keep a ref to them linked to the session. The keepalive action would then fetch the ref for the right session and send KeepAlive messages to the actor.

The SocketActor would, when it receive a Stop message close the socket and destroy the actors that were linked to him.

It's a bit more involved coding, so I am not including snippets, but it would be a simple AKKA system, so you should be able to set it up by checking out the AKKA tutorials if you are not yet used to it.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I am just starting to get into AKKA so it will take me a bit to attempt to code up your suggestion.

Comment: Nice Idea . . . .  .